# Nested Loop to Java Stream Puzzle

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm new to streams in Java 8. I am struggling to figure out how to implement a nested for loop on lists using streams. One list contains messages, one of the fields in the message is the id of an author (not an obj reference, sadly). The other list is the authors, and one of the fields in the author is the author id. The code needs to find the matching author in the authors list for each message in the message list. The working Java code I have (which does not use streams or lambdas) is as follows, my question is how would I rewrite this using streams?  I have tried a couple of things, I thought a flatMap and a filter would be needed, but I cannot seem to get it right.

```
public void showAuthors(List<Message> messages, List<Authors> authors) {
    String authorName=null;
    for (Message message : messages) {
        int authorId = message.getAuthorId();
        for (Authors author : authors) {
            if (author.getId() == authorId)
                authorName = author.getFullName();
                break;
        }
        System.out.println("Message id is " + message.getId() + 
                           " author is " + authorName);
    }
}
```

I've looked at some similar questions here, but I just can't seem to get it right.

Any help is appreciated!

=============================================

Update:  The list of Authors has some null data for the Id fields.  This required that I use filters with the stream operation to create the map of AuthorId,Name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need streams for messages processing, here forEach is more suitable. Nevertheless, streams are useful for authors list to map conversion.

You can use toMap with 3 arguments to avoid possible authors duplication in authors list (original code avoids this).

You can use Optional to avoid possible absence of authos, null id etc. - each time .map returns null, Optional becomes Optional::Empty, so further processing for it is skipped up to terminal operation, and ifPresence simply skips empty optionals.

```
Map<Integer, String> authorNames=authors.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Author::getId,
        Author::getFullName,
        (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue));

messages.forEach(
    m -> Optional.of(m)
        .map(Message::getAuthorId)
        .map(authorNames::get)
        .map(name -> "Message id is " + m.getId() + " author is " + name)
        .ifPresent(System.out::println)
);
```

Comment: There is no reason to use an `Optional` for something that is not supposed to be optional. That’s just complicating the entire code. Compare to `messages.forEach( m -> Optional.of(authorNames.get(m.getAuthorId()))  .ifPresent(name -> System.out.println("Message id is " + m.getId() + " author is " + name)) );` Further, we should consider it an error if IDs are not unique, hence, you should not provide a merge function like `(oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue` which silently discards items in the case of such an error.

Comment: Your Optional.of will simply throw NPE if there is no author. Old code skipped message in this case - new code should do the same unless you have direct question to fix it (and M Watson does not express it). Also old code simply worked for duplicated IDs and it's again a question for proper specification.

Comment: Yes, it should have been `Optional.ofNullable`, otherwise I didn’t use `Optional`, that was the actual point of my comment, don’t complicate the code with `Optional` for things which aren’t optional. Speaking of “new code should do the same”, the old code would match `null` IDs while your use of `Optional` leads to treating `null` IDs like never matching. Regarding duplicates, the old code doesn’t handle them, it just ignores them due to short-circuiting. That’s different to using a duplicate dropping merge function explicitly.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use something like this: a `stream` of authors into a `map` (filtering out null IDs), followed by a `messages.forEach` to print out the message ID and author?

Comment: @Holger Old code will throw NPE in "int authorId =" line, so it will not survive null author's id, and thus will skip null ids in messages, but never properly match them. And generally sequence of direct function references in separate lines is more readable than combination of direct calculation wrapped in optional constructor. Compiler optimizer makes good code in this case if you use function references - as effective as direct dot-notations sequence.

Answer (score 2):

After trying some of the suggestions above, I quickly realized that the authors data has some objects with no Id, just names (apparently they serve a dual purpose...it's not my design!).

So, I wrote the following based on help/hints from the answers above:

```
public void showAuthors(List<Message> messages, List<Reference> authors) {
Map<Integer, String> authorsById = authors.stream()
    .filter(author -> !(author.getId() == null))
    .filter(name -> !(name.getFullName() == null))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Reference::getId, Reference::getFullName));

messages.forEach(
    message -> System.out.println("Message id is " + message.getId() + 
              " Author is " + authorsById.get(message.getSenderId())));
```

Is there anything wrong with this solution?

Also, I'm new to stackoverflow (as I'm sure you could tell)...is there a way I can give all 3 of the responders something for helping?  Is that what upvoting is for?

Meg

Comment: Also, some of the author objects have ids but not names.

Comment: It's ok approach in general, the question is about null checks on possibly every step. Production code should be written with understanding what happens for each class of input, and every such case you meet in production should be covered by unit test. For example, original code skips messages without proper author and your code prints messageId+null author name. Is it indended? As for give something to all - you need to select 1 answer if you are satisfied and want to "close the topic", but feel free to upvote as many as you like.

Comment: Thanks Alexander.  When I tried to upvote it told me since I was so new it would note the vote, but not increase the total...boo!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're doing `mxn` comparison, so it's better to create a Map between `authorId -> author` to avoid `O(n)` lookup on authors:

```
Map<Integer, Author> authorMaps = authors.stream().collect(toMap(Author::getId, Function.identity()));
```

Now you can get the author for each message like this:

```
messages.stream().filter(m -> authorMaps.containsKey(m.getAuthorId()))
        .forEach(m -> 
            System.out.println("Message id is " + m.getId() + 
                           " author is " + authorMaps.get(m.getAuthorId()). getFullName());
        );
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this and realized (after an NPE, that some of the author objects have no Id.  So I think I could just add a `.filter` to the creation of the authorMaps, yes?

Comment: Add a .filter before the check

Answer (score 1):

In the first place to me your current logic is wrong. It breaks the inner loop if the condition is not satisfied for the first time and for all messages you get the previous author or some invalid results like so.

```
Message id is 1 author is AuthOne
Message id is 2 author is AuthOne
Message id is 4 author is AuthOne
```

Here's the corrected one.

```
public static void showAuthors(List<Message> messages, List<Author> authors) {
    String authorName = null;
    for (Message message : messages) {
        int authorId = message.getAuthorId();
        for (Author author : authors) {
            if (author.getId() == authorId) {
                authorName = author.getFullName();
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Message id is " + message.getId() + " author is " + authorName);
    }
}
```

You have to break the loop only after the first `Author` is found. Here's the equivalent `stream` counterpart with linear time complexity.

```
Map<Integer, String> authorsById = authors.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Author::getId, Author::getFullName));
Map<Integer, String> authorNameAgainstId = messages.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Message::getId, m -> authorsById.get(m.getAuthorId())));
```

Comment: Exactly right on the logic, forgot the braces on the if-statement.   Careless.

Comment: Thanks for your help.